# Impact of Java 1.7 on Solr 5.2.1

Tags: java, solr, lucene

When I start my Solr instance I get the following:

```
WARNING: Java version 1.7.0_51 has known bugs with Lucene and requires the -XX:-UseSuperWord flag. Please consider upgrading your JVM.
```

I would like to find a list of these bugs to see if they impact my system, but can't find them online. Does anyone know where they live?

Thanks

Comment: Is simply upgrading to Java 1.8 an option?

Comment: Have a look at this: -
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7460

Comment: @AmitBhati Thanks, I saw that one before. That one is a bug for the code that parses the java version, nothing Solr related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Lucene JavaBugs](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/JavaBugs). There you can find the corresponding [Lucene Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5212) and [Oracle Bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024830) for the "SEGV or serious index corrumption" bug which needs the UseSuperWord property.